# Error while installing chkTex

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-make

I am trying to install ChkTex on the Ubuntu version 16.04. For that, I downloaded the manual and software. I am currently following [the manual for installation.](http://www.nongnu.org/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf) But, when I try to use the command `make`, it gives me the following error:

```
gcc -lpcreposix -lpcre -o chktex ChkTeX.o FindErrs.o OpSys.o Resource.o Utility.o -ltermcap 
FindErrs.o: In function `CheckSilentRegex':
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:1256: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regcomp'
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:1277: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regexec'
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:1288: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regerror'
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:1261: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regerror'
FindErrs.o: In function `CheckRest':
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:920: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regexec'
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:931: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regerror'
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:878: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regcomp'
/home/mala/Downloads/chktex-1.7.6/FindErrs.c:885: undefined reference to `pcreposix_regerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'chktex' failed
make: *** [chktex] Error 1
```

What is the reason for the error and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please note that [chktex (1.7.4-1ubuntu2)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/chktex) is available for Ubuntu 16.04 from the Universe repository.

---

The error appears to be because the relevant libraries are placed incorrectly in the `gcc` command line - see [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Digging deeper, that can be traced back to the libraries apparently being added to `LDFLAGS` instead of `LIBS`

```
LIBS=-ltermcap -lpcreposix -lpcre
LDFLAGS=-lpcreposix -lpcre
```

so that the recipe

```
chktex: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o chktex $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

expands to

```
gcc -lpcreposix -lpcre -o chktex ChkTeX.o FindErrs.o OpSys.o Resource.o Utility.o -ltermcap
```

instead of the required

```
gcc -o chktex ChkTeX.o FindErrs.o OpSys.o Resource.o Utility.o -ltermcap -lpcreposix -lpcre
```

You can work around this by manually editing the Makefile, changing the lines to

```
LIBS=-ltermcap -lpcreposix -lpcre
LDFLAGS=
```